# Remove folder from url slug

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have little to no experience with the following problem so I am turning to the community for help.

My Forum is installed within a folder named`forum` within my root directory. When users try to login from a discussion or a thread, they get redirected to a 404 url.

The reason why they are getting redirected to 404-page is because *the forum creates a second `forum` slug within the url*, here is an example:

**When Viewing a Thread**

http://www.example.com/forum/discussion/1/letsTalk

*The above is the correct url,* HOWEVER, when user tries to login they get redirected to the following url

**When Logging IN**
http://www.example.com/forum/forum/discussion/1/letsTalk

*Notice the `forum` appearing twice in the above url.*

### Solution

I am guessing this can be fixed within the `htaccess` file by creating a re-write rule, which is simple enough. However my problem comes in when users view other threads with a different url than the one given above.

Thus, I need to find a way to remove the second forum appearing within the URL which...I am not sure how to tackle? Can this be fixed within the `htaccess` or will source code need to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

In your head section in the html you should put

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/forum"/>
```

This will make relative urls get prepended with the given base.

Then you should make another .htaccess inside the forum subdirectory
It should contain the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/
```

This will make relative URLs used in your backend get prepended with the base.